# MongoDB "Unable to establish lock" error on mounted drive using Docker and Lustre

Tags: mongodb, docker, cluster-computing, lustre

I am trying to use Docker to containerize a MongoDB instance using a drive mounted on host.

Using the `mongo:latest` image:

```
[user@dcos-master ~]$ docker run -d --name mongo -v /local/cluster/drive:/data/db mongo:latest
```

But constantly fails with:

```
exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Function not implemented. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

Considered it a permission problem so I have attempted opening up the permissions to 777 on the host directory and also just running the mongod instance as root and I get the same problem.

There definitely is not another mongod instance running and pointing at the same data directory.

Lastly, something worth pointing out: The only common denominator seems to be the filesystem. Mongod consistently fails on Lustre drives but not on any other filesystem. If I the source directory is on an NFS drive or anything else, it runs great.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/30 may help you

Comment: Can you give some more information about the Docker version, the host OS, and how Docker was installed? If this is on macOS, then `/local/cluster/drive` isn't a valid host mount by default.

Comment: Docker version: 1.11.2 and is running on CentOS 7.3.1611 The install was a standard yum install using the instructions on Docker's docs. Let me know if you need more specifics.

Comment: Try to `run` container with "--privileged" flag. It may help

Comment: tried that too, to the same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://anilmaurya.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/abaqus-with-lustre-file-system/

By default lustre doesn't have the the flock feature [1], you have to add the "flock" option when mounting [2] the filesystem to make it work [3]

[1]

```
$ touch temp
$ strace -e flock perl -e 'open(FH, "+< temp"); flock(FH, 2) or exit 1; sleep 1; close(FH);'
flock(3, LOCK_EX)                       = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

[2]

You have to umount and mount the filesystem as lustre doesn't support the `-o remount` option:

```
$ mount | grep /data
mgs@tcp:/data on /data type lustre (rw,lazystatfs)
$ mount -o remount,flock /data
$ mount | grep /data
mgs@tcp:/data on /data type lustre (rw,lazystatfs)

# umount /data
# mount -t lustre -o rw,flock mgs@tcp:/data /data
$ mount | grep /data
mgs@tcp:/data on /data type lustre (rw,flock,lazystatfs)
```

[3]

```
$ strace -e flock perl -e 'open(FH, "+< temp"); flock(FH, 2) or exit 1; sleep 1; close(FH);'
flock(3, LOCK_EX)                       = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job :)